# Mysql fails in php but works in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I've made this a lot of times but now I can't :(

The insert allways return false but if I execute the same SQL script (taked from the output) it inserts in the database without any problem. I'm connected to the database because some values are fetched from another table.

This is my code:

```
     $query = "INSERT INTO normotensiones(fecha,macropera,pozo,equipo_pmx,equipo_compania,paciente,sexo,edad,id_compania,otra_compania,puesto,ta,tum,ove,coordinador) 
                                VALUES('$fecha','$macropera','$pozo','$equipo_pmx','$equipo_compania','$paciente','$sexo',$edad,$id_compania,'$otra_compania','$puesto','$ta','$tum','$ove','$coordinador')";
        if (mysql_query($query,$connection)){
            //OK
        } else {
            $errno = mysql_errno();
            $error = mysql_error();
            mysql_close($connection);
            die("<br />$errno - $error<br /><br />$query");
            exit;
        }
```

The output is:

0 -

```
INSERT INTO normotensiones(fecha,macropera,pozo,equipo_pmx, equipo_compania,paciente,sexo,edad,id_compania, otra_compania,puesto,ta,tum,ove,coordinador) 
                VALUES('20111001','P. ALEMAN 1739','P. ALEMAN 1715','726', 'WDI 838','SERGIO AYALA','M',33,21, '','','110/70','ROBERTO ELIEL CAMARILLO','VICTOR HUGO RAMIREZ','LIC. PABLO GARCES')
```

Looks like there are no error, but allways execute the code in the else part of the if instruction. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `$connection` is the problem?

Comment: Stop using `myql_*` and start using `PDO`. Now.

Comment: Can you post the column structure as well it seems like the error might be one of the column types.

Comment: what `$connection` has?, what happen if you put in the if 
`if (mysql_query($query,$connection)){
            echo 'ok';
        }`

Comment: I think that the $connection variables is OK, because I fetch values from another table without any problem previously in the same proogram.

Comment: All columns are VARCHAR except edad and id_compania, wich are INT's. But if the structure is the problem, the mysql_error() gets a value after trying to execute the query.

Comment: @Jeff, happens the same with your suggestion :(

Comment: @AlienWebguy I'll start using mysqli_* like PHP site recommends.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be you are missing the `mysql_select_db` line after the connection.

After the connection with the database is established you need to select a DB. Please make sure you have selected the Database that your desired table resides in.

And you can even use the following snippets to get some useful informated through mysql_errors.

```
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');

    if (!$connection) {
        die('<br>Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if (!mysql_select_db('db_name')) {
       die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

And try you insert query after these lines of code. All the best.

Comment: Thanks I found the mistake... the code I posted is inside a function and I must to add the follow instruction: **global $connection**

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others concerning the column types. INT is one of the only data types that do not require single quotes.

There are two blank strings. There is a possibility that the variables are not defined, and therefore giving you a PHP exception (not even in the MySql yet) but that requires stricter-than-normal exception settings. I would personally look into the $connection variable. Before the SQL query statement, put this and send us the cleaned results:

```
echo '<pre>'.var_dump($connection, true).'</pre>';
```

Additionally, on your mysql_connect function call, put

```
OR die('No connection')
```

afterwords. Do the same thing with the mysql_select_db function, changing it to 'No DB Select' obviously.

Ultimately, we will need more information. But changing to mysqli is very desirable.

Oh! And make sure the permissions for the user you are connecting as are not changed. Sometimes I find people who connect to PhpMyAdmin using one user account but a different account in their PHP code. This is problematic, and will lead to problems eventually, as you forget the different accounts, at times.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, I ommited the **global $connection** because the code is inside a function.